# How to subscribe on the keyboard layout changing

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, keyboard

If I run this script it returns the same value regardless of the current keyboard layout.

How to subscribe on the keyboard layout changing?

```js
const KeyboardLayout = require('keyboard-layout');
const Cron = require('cron').CronJob;
new Cron(
    '* * * * * *',
    function() {
        const layout = KeyboardLayout.getCurrentKeyboardLayout().replace('com.apple.keylayout.', '');
        console.log('layout', layout);
    },
    null,
    true,
    'America/Los_Angeles'
);
```